# Is it possible to filter out user questions based on their location?

Tags: support, low-quality-posts

Most of us know that the quality of questions asked by new users is collated to some extent to their location in the world. I want to be able to filter out questions from users who live in certain parts of the world.

Is it possible to block these questions or filter them from my view?

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't require users to make their location public, and doing providing this option would effectively have them to that (in an obtuse, indirect way).

Comment: I think you can userscript it to a certain extent based on user name.

Comment: @TZHX, the IP address rather gives the location away

Comment: @Ian Yes... but on what page can you, as a regular user see the IP address of another user?

Comment: @DeerHunter,  "user name" may not be a good option, as I have found that people who parents are from these counties but live/work in the UK are some of the BEST programmers I have worked with.

Comment: Ian, this is private information - Stack Exchange would lose a ton of rep (no pun intended) if you could derive user location by comparing uncensored and censored versions.

Comment: Yes, I was about to make the same observation. A SOL situation, I guess

Comment: @IanRingrose I've edited this a bit to get to the nitty gritty of what you are asking.

Comment: Hm, don't know how useful this would be for SO, but filtering out questions from US based accounts on Politics.SE wouldn't be a terrible idea... ;)

Comment: @Yannis, being able to filter out questions from US based accounts on Politics.SE may make it a site worth my time looking at :-)

Comment: I believe that, at least to a certain extent, cultural differences are at work here. So maybe create Stack Overflow in the languages specific to these parts of the world?

Comment: @S.L.Barth, and that language is English for a very large extend.   (Due to most workplaces using English, as their customers are English speaking.)

Comment: @IanRingrose Many of them are far from fluent in English. It is, after all, a language very different from their native tongues. If they had an SO in their native languages, they might prefer it.

Comment: @S.L.Barth, That would be logical, apart from a lot of their universities using English for teaching, as the students consider English to be of more value then their native tongues.

Comment: if location reliably correlates with question quality, this would better go to algorithm that feeds questions into [meta-tag:triage] (since triaged questions are visible only to reviewers, this would indirectly address your question)

Answer (score 18):

Nope, it's not possible.

***We will not profile anyone based on their location, name or anything else that isn't testimonial on their part.*** What is testimonial is their behavior - and that's fair game for analysis. We just have to do a better job of it, and we're close.

The system already takes the history of questions asked from your network into consideration when it decides what should head straight to triage. It doesn't look at *where* you are, it just looks at how many bad questions have recently come from your network neighborhood. Or, offices full of folks not getting off so well. That had a pretty profound impact, but we're going *purely* on history and an automatic kick into triage is every bit as likely to happen to someone in the UK or US as it would be to someone in Guam. Note - this is just one piece of signal evaluated when the system makes that decision.

What we positively, absolutely, undeniably and rather urgently need to do is put a lot more thinking into the systems that detect anomalous voting. It's a headache for moderators, the tools make innocent stuff look pretty shady, and the tools don't effectively help moderators weed out voting rings without a lot of manual help from us. What we have looks mostly at 'revenge' and 'super fan' patterns, which was the problem we were solving at the time.

The good news? We've made some pretty good strides in that direction to the point that not only can we identify rings, we can also graph them, figure out the leaders and more - without a human having to get involved. In an ideal world, mods only see edge cases where an automatic conclusion can't be made. It would be less badgering of people that really are voting for the quality of something, and a whole lot *more* badgering of people running complex rings.

Comment: Sorting out the informal office voting rings may enable the “network neighbourhood” based analysis to do its job a lot better.

Comment: It will be interested to see how many people get question bans on the day that the voting rings are “undone”…….

Comment: Is there a system in place to stop someone getting a triage review task when the posting was done by someone in the same network neighbourhood?

Comment: @IanRingrose No. The check is way ahead of triage when the question is submitted. We also check for stuff like how hard of a time someone had actually getting the question to post (if you had to try 3 times, there's a good chance someone should look at it before it gets visibility elsewhere). _Some_ of that metadata is preserved. I'm going to take a couple of hours today and spend it just working on triaging questions because I haven't for a while. I can see how 100 "hopeless crap" in a row would create a monotony, we might be able to fix that.

Answer (score 7):

No. It's not currently possible.

---

Not answering the question:

I don't agree with your initial premise, and without data I suspect you're engaging in a bit of confirmation bias.

I regularly see appalling questions where my initial assumption is *"English is not the OP's first language"*. I then look at their profile and they're based in the UK or the US.

I've also see great first questions from users where English is not the first language of their country.

The number of deleted, recent, questions, by new users, split by country then weighted by the percentage of users from that country on SO should provide an estimation of whether there *might* be a case to answer. Even then I doubt it, I would expect that the questions of users who speak decent English (wherever they're from in the world) are a lot less likely to get deleted than the questions of those users whose English is poorer.

Just because someone isn't perfect at communicating in the language of the site doesn't necessarily mean that their question is bad.

Comment: Hmpf. I think the OP didn't want to split english-as-first-language and the rest, but a bit more selectively. Not sure about it, but there are certainly patterns... which doesn't mean it's a good or even feasible idea.

Answer (score -6):

In my experience, the english as a second language issue should really be separated from the low quality questions from new users issue.

I know that a low quality question with a poor grasp of the language tends to stick out a lot more, but that is simply a conformation bias. Because they stick in the mind it's easier to remember how terrible they are...

On the other hand there are plenty of not-so-bad questions from people who obviously struggle with writing in english that are resolved with a simple edit. Because these are easily fixed, and usually get fixed pretty quickly, they don't stick out.

**Long story short. If it can be salvaged with an edit, do so. If it can't, vote to close as unclear and move on.**

Comment: Does it really answer the question as stated?

Comment: Where do you get the idea that the point is "english as a first language or not"?