# Does Reputation correlate with location?

Tags: discussion, reputation, data-explorer

Reading through reputation-gaining posts and posting behavior analyses I get the impression that the day of time a question or answer is written affects its hit counter and voting score.

Does this lead to a measurable reputation disadvantage for SO users living in timezones different from the typical SO user's one (read: different from American timezones?).

Comment: I've seen that asked recently. The mere essence was, that location isn't exactly determinable for a user.

Comment: oh, well - then sorry for the duplicate. Do you have the link by chance?

Comment: I've been referring to this one actually: [Is it possible to filter out user questions based on their location?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316075/is-it-possible-to-filter-out-user-questions-based-on-their-location). It's related, certainly not a duplicate.

Comment: Sure, being active during business hours matters to the number of views your post gets.  Europe has the sweet spot, located conveniently between Southern Asia and the Americas.  Australia and Oceania is worst.